# Publisher of foreign-language citation - do I translate "Gobierno de" to "Government of"?

Tags: citations, translation

The publication is in English.

Gobierno de Perú. Ministerio de Agricultura. 2012. Plan estratégico sectorial multiannual 2012-2016. Lima.

or should that be:

Government of Peru. Ministry of Agriculture. 2012. Plan estratégico sectorial multiannual 2012-2016. Lima.

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct answer will depend on your style guide. Usually (e.g. in APA) you don't tranlsate author names, publishers, etc. **You give everything as it was in the original publication, with no changes.**

The only part you do translate (into the language of your paper) is the title of the work you cite, e.g.

> Ministerio de Agricultura. (2012). *Plan estratégico sectorial multiannual 2012-2016* [Multiannual sectoral strategic plan 2012-2016]. Lima: Ministerio de Agricultura. Available online at http://www.minag.gob.pe/portal/download/pdf/marcolegal/normaslegales/resolucionesministeriales/2012/mayo/pesem2012-2016.pdf

I'm just guessing the meaning of the title here, you'll have to correctly translate that yourself.

Do not put "Gobierno de Perú" as part of the author name. The government did not author that document. If Peter Swanwick of the University of Nebraska writes a paper, the author is not "University of Nebraska, Peter Swanwick". Your publication was authored by the ministry of agriculture, not the whole of the government, so the government must not appear as part of the author name.